# Finding the mistake in C++ operator overloading

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I am trying to understand how to overload the '<<' operator. So i wrote a simple test code that I report part of if here:

```
class Buffer {

    vector<char> buffer;

    ...

    ostream& operator<< (ostream& out, const vector<char>& v) {
            out << "[";
            size_t last = v.size() - 1;
            for(size_t i = 0; i < v.size(); ++i) {
                out << v[i];
                if (i != last)
            out << ", ";
            }
            out << "]";
            return out;
    }

    ...

};
```

The way I use the class in the main is the usual but I get the following error. Why?

```
main.cpp:22:10: error: overloaded 'operator<<' must be a binary operator (has 3 parameters)
ostream& operator<< (ostream& out, const vector<char>& v) {
         ^
```

Comment: Implement it as a friend function, not as a method.

Comment: How would you call that operator when it is a member of `Buffer` ?

Comment: Better yet, make it a free function. It's not at all related to your class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It needs to be a binary operator: Since you're adding the operator as a class member, it'll always be called on a instance of that class, like this:

```
Buffer myBuffer;
const vector<char> myVector;
myBuffer << myVector;
```

You should see this as a function equivalent to:

```
myBuffer.DoOperator(myVector);
```

.. which takes only one argument, not two! So you should skip the first argument!

Comment: maybe its just me misreading, but no the operator in OPs code cannot be called like this `myBuffer << myVector`. Also your last sentence seems to be cut off

Answer (score 1):

```
class Buffer {

vector<char> buffer;

...
friend
ostream& operator<< (ostream& out, const Buffer& b) {
        const vector<char>& v=b.buffer;
        out << "[";
        size_t last = v.size() - 1;
        for(size_t i = 0; i < v.size(); ++i) {
            out << v[i];
            if (i != last)
        out << ", ";
        }
        out << "]";
        return out;
}

...

};
```

Comment: I'd write that way more compact with `std::ostream_iterator` ([live example](https://ideone.com/UH5aJt)).

Comment: @HenriMenke I honnestly just copy paste its function and changed its signature to make it usable without any furthur consideration.